# array doesn't get stored in `localStorage` on using `callback`

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to store `item` in an array, `newItemList`, along with present hour and an object, which I get from a server as JSON response, which I parse into a js object. This simply means that a typical element of `newItemList` will be `[item, 13(present_hour), obj]`

Here's the code,

```
 var item;
 //some code to obtain item

 chrome.storage.local.get({'itemList':[]}, function(item){
   var newItemList = item.itemList;
   var d = new Date();

   if (isItemInArray(newItemList,item) == -1) {
     //api call function as callback

     apiCall(function(result){
         newItemList.push([item,d.getHours(),result]);
     });

   } else {
     var indexOfitem = findItem(newItemList,item);//finding item in the array
     if(//some condition){

       apiCall(function(result){
           newItemList[indexOfTab][1] = d.getHours();
           newItemList[indexOfTab][2] = result;
       });

     } else {
       var indexOfitem = findItem(newItemList,item);
       storedApiCall(newItemList[indexOfTab][2]);//sending the stored JSON response
     }
  }
 chrome.storage.local.set({itemList: newItemList});
 })

 function apiCall(callback){
    //API call, to obtain the JSON response from the web server
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);//parsing the JSON response to js object

      callback(myObj);
      storedApiCall(myObj);//this function just works fine
     }
    };
  xhttp.open("GET", "example.com", true);
  xhttp.send();
 }
```

`newItemList` isn't getting stored in local storage. It contains of only one element, `[item, present hour, obj(from present apiCall)]`. That's why, only the `if` part of the code runs each time leading to api calls each time, rendering the `else` part obsolete.

I read about `callback` from many famous questions asked around about `asynchronous calls`, but none connected local storage with `callbacks`. Before implementing `callback`, `newItemList` got stored in local storage, but I couldn't obtain the obj from JSON response for the first time, which is the typical behaviour of `asynchronous calls`. 
Suggest edits, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is being executed before the functions given to your calls to `apiCall` are invoked (i.e. with its initial value `item.itemList`):

```
chrome.storage.local.set({itemList: newItemList});
```

This is because callbacks are typically invoked after some asynchronous action completes. In your case, they will be invoked after whatever operation `apiCall` performs is complete, e.g. an HTTP response to an API is received.

So if you move that line into those callback functions, at their end after you have mutated `newItemList`, the `set` call on `chrome.storage.local` will be performed with the changes applied (e.g. `newItemList.push([item,d.getHours(),result])`):

```
chrome.storage.local.get({'itemList':[]}, function(item){
    var newItemList = item.itemList;
    var d = new Date();

    if (isItemInArray(newItemList,item) == -1) {
      //api call function as callback

      apiCall(function(result){
          newItemList.push([item,d.getHours(),result]);
          chrome.storage.local.set({itemList: newItemList});
      });

    } else {
      var indexOfitem = findItem(newItemList,item);//finding item in the array
      if(//some condition){

        apiCall(function(result){
            newItemList[indexOfTab][1] = d.getHours();
            newItemList[indexOfTab][2] = result;
            chrome.storage.local.set({itemList: newItemList});
        });

      } else {
        var indexOfitem = findItem(newItemList,item);
        storedApiCall(newItemList[indexOfTab][2]);//sending the stored JSON response
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that when the execution arrives on the **chrome.storage.local.set({itemList: newItemList});** line, the variable is not set yet because the **XMLHttpRequest** is async you have to add an **chrome.storage.local.set** in your callback function or use a promise then set your local storage value